# How to append findall results to list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a website for all links that have the attribute `nofollow`.
I want to print that list, one link by one.
However I failed to append the results of `findall()` to my list `box`(my attempt is in brackets).

What did I do wrong?

```
import sys
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


page = urllib2.urlopen(sys.argv[1]).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()

box = []

for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True, attrs = {'rel' : 'nofollow'}):
#    box.extend(anchor['href'])
     print anchor['href']

# print box
```

Comment: Failed? How? What is the exact error?

Comment: @CRUSADER: The individual characters of each URL are appended to `box`, as opposed to whole strings, is my guess. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over `soup.findAll` so each `anchor` is not itself a list; use `.append()` for individual elements:

```
box.append(anchor['href'])
```

You could also use a list comprehension to grab all `href` attributes:

```
box = [a['href'] for a in soup.findAll('a', href=True, attrs = {'rel' : 'nofollow'})]
```

Comment: Right, I mixed up `.append()` and `.extend()`!

Comment: @MartinBetz: Indeed you did! :-)